# A question about connected subsets of $[0,1]^2$

Tags: gn.general-topology

If $S⊂[0,1]^2$ intersects every connected subset of $[0,1]^2$ with a full projection on the $x$-axis, must $S$ have a connected component with a full projection on the $y$-axis?

**An equivalent form：**

If $S⊂[0,1]^2$ intersects every connected subset of $[0,1]^2$ with a full projection on the $x$-axis and $T⊂[0,1]^2$ intersects every connected subset of $[0,1]^2$ with a full projection on the $y$-axis, must $S\cap T\neq \emptyset$?

**The motivation of this question:**

The question came to me when I thought about the Brouwer fixed-point theorem:

Let $f=(f_1,f_2)$ be a continuous function mappping $[0,1]^2$ to itself. Then
$$S\triangleq\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2:f_1(x,y)=x\}$$
intersects every connected subset of $[0,1]^2$ with a full projection on the $x$-axis and
$$T\triangleq\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2:f_2(x,y)=y\}$$
intersects every connected subset of $[0,1]^2$ with a full projection on the $y$-axis.

**My further question:**

If we assume that $S\subset [0,1]^2$ is a close set, what is the answer to my question, that is, if a close set $S⊂[0,1]^2$ intersects every connected subset of $[0,1]^2$ with a full projection on the $x$-axis, must $S$ have a connected component with a full projection on the $y$-axis?

Comment: Shorter version: If $S \subset [0,1]^2$ intersects every subset of $[0,1]^2$ with a full projection on the $x$-axis, must $S$ have a connected component with a full projection on the $y$-axis?

Comment: ... every *connected* subset of $[0,1]^2$ with a full projection

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension

Comment: @mathstackexchange31415926 I made that comment above. I'd suggest editing your question to put it in Matt F.'s form (corrected) --- otherwise people have to go to the comments to see the "easy" version.

Comment: @Matt F Thanks for your shorter form.

Comment: @Nik Weaver Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome, good question BTW.

Comment: I parsed the grammar wrong at first.  I think the hypothesis is "For every connected subset $C$ which has a full projection (i.e. $\pi_x(C) = [0,1]$), we have $S \cap C \ne \emptyset$".  Right?  I first thought it was saying that the intersection should have full projection.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Yes, your later thoughts are right.

Comment: Another equivalent statement: if $S$ separates the left and right sides of the square, then it connects the top and the bottom sides. It seems that if $S$ was closed, then there would be a component of $S$ that separated the sides. It then is easy to see that this component intersects both top and the bottom.

Comment: FWIW I thought the original form of the question was less ambiguous, this new form I read as requiring $\pi_1(S \cap A) = [0,1]$ for every connected $A$ and had to pull up the edit history.

Comment: About your additional question: usually, it is better to start a new question.

Comment: @Anton Petrunin: Thank you for your reminding. I have deleted the new question and start a new question.

Comment: Too late --- you get an answer already. (I wrote it for the future.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A counterexample to this statement was posted as a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824227/do-partitions-of-a-square-into-two-sets-always-connect-one-pair-of-opposite-edge#comment5823373_2824227) by Dejan Govc to the Math StackExchange question, [Do partitions of a square into two sets always connect one pair of opposite edges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2824227/1726).

For $0 < r < \tfrac{1}{2}$, let $S_r$ be the boundary of the square $\bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}-r,\tfrac{1}{2}+r\bigr]\times \bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}-r,\tfrac{1}{2}+r\bigr]$, and let
$$
S = \{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\} \;\;\cup \bigcup_{r\in \mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1/2)} S_r.
$$
Note that no connected component of $[0,1]^2\setminus S$ has full projection onto the $x$-axis, and therefore any connected subset of $[0,1]^2$ with full projection onto the $x$-axis must intersect $S$.  However, no connected component of $S$ has full projection onto the $y$-axis.

Comment: My God, that is so much easier than I expected!

Comment: Excellent -- but shoudn't the credits go to @Dejan Govc ?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Perhaps I should award a new bounty for his answer to another question?

Comment: I don't know, my comment was just a spontaneous idea. Finding a relevant source is a major point for many MO answers, so that you also deserve the credits.

Comment: The answer here clearly credits Govc. I think that's sufficient.

Comment: Thank you very much for Jim Belk's help and the beautiful counterexample posted as a comment by Dejan Govc!

Answer (score 4):

This is an answer to the updated question.

**Proposition:** If a closed $S\subset [0,1]\times [0,1]$ intersects every connected set with a full projection onto the $x$-axis, then it has a component with a full projection onto the $y$-axis.

First, without loss of generality we may assume that $S$ does not intersect the left and the right sides of the square (otherwise, consider the same problem but for $[-1,2]\times [0,1]$. Let $\Pi=(0,1)\times (0,1)$, which is homeomorphic to the full plane.

Pick a point on the left side take a disk $D$ around this point that does not intersect $S$. Take $x$ in $D\cap \Pi$. Do the same on the right side and get $E$ and $y$.  Let $S'=S\cap \Pi$, which is closed in $\Pi$.

Now $S'$ separates $x$ and $y$ within $\Pi$ (meaning any connected set in $\Pi$ that contains $x$ and $y$ has to intersect $S'$. Indeed, if a connected set $F\subset \Pi$ contains $x$ and $y$, then $F\cup D\cup E$ has a full projection onto the $x$-axis, and so has to intersect $S$, but since $D$ and $E$ do not, it follows that $F\cap S'=F\cap S\ne\varnothing$ (the first equality follows from $F\subset\Pi$).

Since $S'$ is closed in $\Pi$, which is homeomorphic to the plane, by a Theorem V.14.3 in the book *Newman - Elements of topology of planar sets of points*, there is a component $C$ of $S'$ that separates $x$ and $y$ in $\Pi$. Clearly, $C$ has a full projection on the $y$-axis (and so it is $(0,1)$), since otherwise we could sneak in a horizontal segment between the left and right sides, which would contradict the separation.

Since $S$ is closed, $\overline{C}$ is a connected compact subset of $S$. Hence, $C$ has a compact projection onto $y$ axis, and so this projection is $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is the name of the book you mentioned Elements of the topology of plane sets of points? I can not find Theorem 14.3. The book has only seven chapters.

Comment: @mathstackexchange31415926 yes, sorry, I didn't notice that it has a strange numeration. It's Theorem 14.3 in chapter V

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have found the theorem!

Comment: I am sorry! I have deleted the updated question and start a new question here (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393520/a-further-question-about-connected-subsets-of-0-12). Please remove your answer to the new question, so I can accept your answer! Thanks again!

Comment: @mathstackexchange31415926 i don't think this is necessary

Comment: Ok, thanks again!